# Using jME3 in WindowBuilder (Eclipse) SWT

Tags: java, eclipse, blender, windowbuilder, jmonkeyengine

I have created a simple interface using the Eclipse WindowBuilder plugin. My goal is to load blender models using jMonkeyEngine (jME3). I believe that jME3 only supports swing and AWT, while WindowBuilder mainly uses SWT.

Currently I have a window with a TabFolder. On the current tab (displayed below) is a composite (which allows me to freely place SWT components, like the button). I would like to have my model somehow displayed in the area specified below.

[image: GUI with a tab folder and composite]

I am fairly new to jME3 and WindowBuilder, so I would appreciate a thorough response or some resources to help me with this.

Comment: Have you tried the jme3 forums? I haven't been over there in a while, but they were very helpful when I was.

Comment: @Catalyst I have already checked there, haven't asked a question yet (maybe I'll try asking), but most of the answers were for swing and awt.